# 3 Level authorization structure

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on banking application, I want to  add a feature of maker,checker and authorize for every record in a table. I am explaining in below details

Suppose I have one table called invmast table. There are 3 users  one is maker, 2nd one is checker and last one is authorize. So when maker user creates a transaction in database then this record is not live (means this record can not be available in invmast table). Once checker checked the record and authorizer authorized the record  the record will go live ( means this record will insert in invmast table ). Same thing is applicable for update and delete also. So I want a table structure how to achieve this in real time. Please advice if any.
I am using vb.net and sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Reads like a homework assignment.....

Lots of ways to solve this, here's a common design pattern:

Have an invmast_draft table that is identical to invmast but has an additional status column in the table. Apps need to be aware of this table, status column and what its values mean. In your case, it can have at least 3 values - draft, checked, authorized. Makers first create a transaction in this table. Once maker is done, the row is committed with the value "draft" in the status column. Checker then knows there's a new row to check and does his job. When done, row is updated with status set to checked. Authorizer does her thing. When authorizer updates the status as "authorized" you can then copy or move the row to the final invmast table rightaway. Alternatively, you can have a process that wakes up periodically to copy/move batches of rows. All depends on your business requirements. All kinds of optimizations can be performed here but you get the general idea.